# std::stringstream and std::ios::binary

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, iostream

I want to write to a `std::stringstream` without any transformation of, say line endings.

I have the following code:

```
void decrypt(std::istream& input, std::ostream& output)
{
    while (input.good())
    {
        char c = input.get()
        c ^= mask;
        output.put(c);

        if (output.bad())
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("Output to stream failed.");
        }
    }
}
```

The following code works like a charm:

```
std::ifstream input("foo.enc", std::ios::binary);
std::ofstream output("foo.txt", std::ios::binary);
decrypt(input, output);
```

If I use a the following code, I run into the `std::runtime_error` where output is in error state.

```
std::ifstream input("foo.enc", std::ios::binary);
std::stringstream output(std::ios::binary);
decrypt(input, output);
```

If I remove the `std::ios::binary` the decrypt function completes without error, but I end up with CR,CR,LF as line endings.

I am using VS2008 and have not yet tested the code on gcc. Is this the way it supposed to behave or is MS's implementation of `std::stringstream` broken?

Any ideas how I can get the contents into a `std::stringstream` in the proper format? I tried putting the contents into a `std::string` and then using `write()` and it also had the same result.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

AFAIK, the `binary` flag only applies to `fstream`, and `stringstream` never does linefeed conversion, so it is at most useless here.

Moreover, the flags passed to `stringstream`'s ctor should contain `in`, `out` or both. In your case, `out` is necessary (or better yet, use an `ostringstream`) otherwise, the stream is in not in output mode, which is why writing to it fails.

`stringstream` ctor's "mode" parameter has a default value of `in|out`, which explains why things are working properly when you don't pass any argument.

Comment: The `output.bad()` was resolved by using

    `std::stringstream output(std::stringstream::in|std::stringstream::out|std::stringstream::binary);`

And `std::ios::binary` did nothing. The error was that an other piece of code that wrote contents to file (for debugging) was not using `std::ios::binary`.

Comment: Are you sure binary is not used? From the doc : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream/basic_istringstream

Comment: @galinette: Yes, I'm pretty sure. I never saw it having an effect in practice and the standard specifies its effect only when talking about file-based streams. Similarly, the "binary mode" link on the page you mention points to a page about "C-style *file* I/O". Of course, if you have proofs of the contrary, please share them so that the answer can be updated.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/stringstream/ says for c++11, "Other values of type ios_base::openmode (such as ios_base::app) may also be specified, although whether they have an effect on stringstream objects depends on the library implementation." So, I personally will take the safe side and use: stringstream ss(stringstream::binary); (note that ios_base::binary and stringstream::binary are the same values for me in Visual Studio 2015, both being 32).

Answer (score -1):

Try to use

```
std::stringstream output(std::stringstream::out|std::stringstream::binary);
```

Comment: According to documentation, you can use `ios_base::in`, `ios_base::out` and `ios_base::ate` in C++11.

Comment: std::stringstream::binary worked for me, thank you!