# serialization with QT network and deserialization with Boost

Tags: c++, qt, boost-asio, boost-serialization, qtnetwork

In a first time i want to thanks **HostileFork** to help me to explain my problem.
Thanks you !

i'm trying to build a client and a server who send their data through a binary protocol.

my problem is i want to send a class from a QT client to a Boost Server. My header(one integer who is the size of my class) is writting on the socket. When i want to read the header on the server side, i can't get the good integer(instead of that i have an big number like -13050660). I think that the problem come to the deserialization on the server but i am not sure.

This is the technique that my Qt client code uses to write the number 10 to onto a socket:

```
QByteArray paquet;
QDataStream out(&paquet, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
out << (quint32) 0;
out.device()->seek(0);
out << (quint32) (10);
cout << "Writing " << sizeof(quint32) << " bytes to socket." << endl;
```

Then I try to read it on a server process, which uses boost's async_read():

```
this->Iheader.resize(size, '\0'); // Iheader is a vector of char
async_read(
    this->socket,
    buffer(this->Iheader),
    bind(
        &Client::endRead,
        cli,
        placeholders::error,
        placeholders::bytes_transferred)
);
```

Here's the function that operates on the string result:

```
#ifdef WIN32
    #define MYINT INT32
    #include <Windows.h>
#else
    #define MYINT int
#endif

void Client::endRead(const error_code& error, size_t nbytes)
{
    if (!error && nbytes == sizeof(MYINT)) {
        cout << "Read " << sizeof(MYINT) << " bytes from a socket." << endl;
        istringstream stream(this->connection->getIheader(nbytes));
        stream >> this->Isize;
        cout << "Integer value read was " << this->Isize << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "Could not read " << sizeof(MYINT) << " bytes." << endl;
    }
}
```

I do get the 32-bit signed integer (4 bytes), but it is not ten, instead it is something like -1163005939. Anyone have and ideas why this is not working?

The server and the client are both on launching on Windows7 pro, 64-bit.

Comment: TL;DR.  Is this really the simplest case you could provide to diagnose the problem?  Can you find a non-working example that is significantly briefer?  Why did you tell us the size you read back and not include the size you thought you wrote?  (Also, it's not necessary to paste a screen capture in order to show a number...copying and pasting the number is better, and also allows others to copy/paste it as well.)  Are the client and server running on the same architecture?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: Isize seems to be not 16 bits long. Too little value. Are you shure you read exactly same length, as you wrote?

Comment: Try paring this down a bit.  Have it write an integer, and then read an integer.  If it doesn't work, then we can dissect it more easily.  If it does work, keep adding parts back in until you add in the line of code that makes it go haywire...then look at that.  http://sscce.org/

Comment: do you mean write an integer (with 10 on value for example) through the socket on the client side ? because before i try to put in place my binary protocol, i succeed to send strings between the client and the server

Comment: well, a sizeof(INT32) == 4 and a sizeof(quint16) == 2. So i will replace quint16 by quint32. I will tell you if it works

Comment: it's not working...same result :(

Comment: @Yumino Yes.  Show a simpler scenario that does not work, if you can.  If it is not necessary to have five strings to show the problem--and one of them (or zero) suffices to demonstrate the issue--why include them all in your question?  You should always be looking for the minimal snippet of code that gives you the problem you can't figure out, instead of pasting large segments that carry along incidental details from your actual codebase...

Comment: ok i try to simplified my problem, i hope it's better for you to understand what i say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're welcome...and thanks for [following my suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8219063/3) on editing the question, and doing the requisite effort to pinpoint the problem more clearly.  So now I can tell you what's wrong.  :)

The behavior of the `<<` and `>>` are different on `QDataStream` than on C++ standard IOstreams.  In the world of classes like `std::stringstream` these operators are called "inserters"/"extractors" and are intended for dealing with information formatted *as text*.  If you want to read a certain number of bytes into a memory address, what you'll want is:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/read/

*(Note that if you wish to read binary data out of something that is not a stringstream, you need to be [using ios::binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311382/stdstringstream-and-stdiosbinary) to keep it from messing with line ending conversions)*

`QDataStream` doesn't follow that convention...it's a good helper for binary data.  Nothing wrong with that...since abstractly speaking the `<<` and `>>` operators are available in the language to be overloaded to do whatever you want within your own class hierarchies.  Qt was free to define its own semantics for its own streams, and they did.

Do heed the advice given by @vitakot about (if possible) using the same methodology for both input and output.  Also heed my warning about [byte-ordering issues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) that start to come up if you aren't careful.

(Good news is that if you are using `QDataStream` it finesses this issue by [taking care of it for you](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qdatastream.html#setByteOrder).)

Be aware that in your code as written, your stringstream is making a copy of the buffer in order to read from it.  I'm not experienced with `boost::asio` or the best practices of `async_read`, but I'm sure there are better ways you might dig around and find.

Comment: arf sorry, it's hard to know how show this kind of problem. i agree with you it's more easier !

Comment: So when you change the code to be like what I have written...does it still not work?  Do both the writing client and the reading server report back 4 bytes?  What's the new "random" value for plugging in 10, and is it consistent?

Comment: Well i have the same problem when i send `10` on the socket. My server is writting `3131961357`

Comment: Yet it reports getting 4 bytes off the socket?  That 3131961357 value is a special number, corresponding to hexadecimal 0xBAADF00D, which is what you get from uninitialized memory in the Microsoft CRT heap... http://www.nobugs.org/developer/win32/debug_crt_heap.html

Comment: yeah i found the problem. I receive the right data. but when i try to convert my result string who contain `[0], [0], [0], [10]` (so the number that i write on the socket) on my size with ` istringstream stream(this->connection->getIheader(nbytes));      stream >> this->Isize;` it's not working.

Comment: See how much better it is when the question is narrowed to its essence and the tangents removed?  Now we can address the specific issues...I've updated my answer!

Comment: Wow..... i never thought about that. are you chuck norris ? :). well i will try this tonight. i will tell you if it works or not but i think it's the solution. Thanks for this !

Comment: is the same time i will read again your warning about byte-orgering issues to be sure to understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

HostileFork is right, from the information we have it is not possible to isolate a bug in your code.

However, I would suggest you to use boost serialization in your Qt client as well. There is no reason to not combine Boost and Qt libraries. Otherwise you will have to deal with a lot of troubles when sending more complicated classes over the network...