# I can't send a header size through the network with Qt and Boost

Tags: c++, qt, boost, network-programming, boost-asio

I try to send a class' size from a Qt client to a Boost server (I made both).

This is the class I want to serialize

```
class Commande
{
public:
        std::string     login;
        std::string     mdp;
        std::string     IP;
        std::string     to;
        std::string     from;
        bool            rep;
        int             nbCmd;
};
```

This is the function I use to serialize and send the `Commande` size and the object.
`_socket` is a QTcpSocket

```
void    BNetwork::sendData(void)
{
    QByteArray  paquet;
    QDataStream out(&paquet, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    Commande    cmd;

    cmd.setCmd(1);
    cmd.setFrom("Paris");
    cmd.setIP("127.0.0.1");
    cmd.setLogin("test1");
    cmd.setMdp("mdp1");
    cmd.setRep(0);
    cmd.setTo("maryline");
    out << (quint32) 0;
    out << cmd;
    out.device()->seek(0);
    out << (paquet.size() - (int)sizeof(quint32));
    this->_socket.write(paquet);
}

QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream &out, Commande &cmd)
{
    QString test(cmd.from.c_str());

        out << (quint32)cmd.nbCmd;
        out << test;
        test = cmd.IP.c_str();
        out << test;
        test = cmd.mdp.c_str();
        out << test;
        out << (quint32)cmd.rep;
        test = cmd.to.c_str();
        out << test;
        return out;
}
```

This is the function I use to convert the header size I received from the QT client.

```
std::string  save = this->connection->getIheader(); \\ this is the string i read on the socket
std::istringstream                      stream(save);
std::cout << save << std::endl;
if (!(stream >> std::dec >> this->Isize))
      throw my_exception("error in endRead()");
```

For an unknown reason, `save` contains "1000", and when I try to convert this string into an integer, it's not working so I think the value I get isn't correct.

The client and the server are running on windows 7 64bits.

Do you have a solution to my problem?

Comment: This [seems strangely familiar](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8217398/1)? (First version of a heavily modified question) Homework maybe? Same user, different account?

Comment: myabe you experience problems between host endianes and network endianess?

Answer (score 1):

First, confirm that when you use `out.device()->seek(0)`, you cause the next writes to prepend as you expect, rather than overwriting the data you've already written, as I expect.

Then, consult [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8219063/965934) to a question that very likely has the same or similar problem.

Let me know in a comment if you need more help.

ETA:`QString`stores data as 16 bit`QChar`, in order to support unicode. `std::string`and`std::istringstream`are reading 8 bit`char`. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/402918/965934). The QChars serialized by QT are likely to cause you trouble down the line. Note also that any 0 (null) char that happens to be in the char sequence returned by getIheader() will terminate `std::string`'s assignment operator.

I recommend replacing the`std::istringstream`with a`QDataStream`, and using that class to read out your data to exactly the types you originally wrote. You can cast from QT types to c++ native types after you've put serialization behind you. Otherwise, you'll have to take lots of care to figure out what QT is doing under the hood & match it by your own effort.

Comment: I use this method as i followed a tutorial i find on the web. I am going to check your solution.
The answer you gave me is my teammate's post and we don't manage to find a solution.

Comment: Can you link the tutorial you mentioned?